# Formated text/labels in UITextView/UITextField

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitextview

Hello Im developing chat application. When I'm creating new group conversation, user is selecting in the tableview and I want to display selected contacts in textview above the tableview, exactly like in the Viber app.
[image]

But I dont know how to display text with background color in textview, also if u press backspace on the keyboard you don't delete just one letter but whole word. Can anybody please  tell me how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Search for a 3rd party token view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [RMSTokenView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rmstokenview), [GCTagList](https://github.com/greenchiu/GCTagList) or [DWTagList](https://github.com/domness/DWTagList). Seems to be exactly what you are looking for!

They both let you use custom fonts and gradients.